# Number of Items in the shipping cart

Tags: expresso-store

Since I was planning to have "You have # items in the cart".
Is it possible to get the number of items in the cart?

I tried to do something like this:

```
{exp:store:cart}

You have {if no_items}0{if:else}{items}{/if} item(s) in the cart 

{/exp:store:cart}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `{order_qty}`.

```
{exp:store:cart}

    {if no_items}Your cart is empty.{/if}

    You have {order_qty} item(s) in the cart.

{/exp:store:cart}
```

:)

Comment: ahh thanks. I tried with {item_qty} and I guess I got confused.

Comment: The Store guys have thought of most things so there's usually a tag to cover most situations. :) Don't forget to mark this answer up if it helped. :)

Comment: Just fixed your code up a little bit - the {if no_items} tag works the same way as {if no_results}, if it is true then nothing else will be displayed.